# Export 20TB from Amazon S3

Tags: storage, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

I have recently inherited 20TB of data after a company takeover. The files are currently stored on an Amazon S3 account which is due to close.

What would be the most cost effective method of exporting all of this data and storing either locally on premises or in the cloud?

My initial thoughts were to use something like Amazon Snowball to send me a physical copy of the data, store half on a new Amazon S3 glacier bucket for infrequent access and the more recent files somewhere else.

Is there a more cost effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowball is a good option if you want the data out of the cloud.

You could [copy the data](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/) to another S3 bucket in the same region. There should be [no cost to copy the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732664/cost-of-copying-files-between-amazon-s3-buckets-in-different-accounts), so long as you do this with an AWS EC2 instance that has an S3 gateway set up. If you run the S3 copy from a computer outside AWS, or on EC2 without an S3 gateway, it will copy over the internet and cost a LOT for bandwidth. You can set the storage class on copy.

Once the data is in the new bucket use lifecycle rules to change the storage class to glacier, deep archive, etc.